# Equivalent findBy and fetchOne from Doctrine in Propel

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, propel

In Doctrine i can do:

```
   $article = Doctrine::getTable('Article')->createQuery('a')->where('a.user_id = ?', $this->getUser()->getAttribute('id') )->fetchOne()
```

and

```
$article = Doctrine::getTable('Article')->findBy('user_id', $this->getUser()->getAttribute('id'));
```

How can i make it in Propel?
I use Symfony 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propel is pretty simple. I'm giving you a propel 1.4 answer. These look like the same query.

```
$article = Doctrine::getTable('Article')->createQuery('a')->where('a.user_id = ?',     $this->getUser()->getAttribute('id') )->fetchOne()

$c = new Criteria; 
$c->add(ArticlePeer::USER_ID, $this->getUser()->getId()); 
$article = ArticlePeer::doSelectOne($c);
```

Answer (score 2):

or for propel 1.6

```
ArticleQuery::create()
    ->filterByUserId($this->getUser()->getId())
    ->findOne();
 //returns Article instance or null
```

or even

```
ArticleQuery::create()
    ->filterByUserId($this->getUser()->getId())
    ->findOneOrCreate();
 //always returns article instance, if created user id will be already initialized
```